# Is there any way to auto reply to certain message string?

Tags: gmail, mac, osx

I was wondering if there's a way to auto reply "Cool!" to all messages with titles "Yo check this out", messages containing the words "Watch this video!", or something similar, an hour after the message was received. Something like that.

Is there?

And if so, can those message types be sent to a ce?

Comment: It's called spam filter.

Comment: It's fairly easy to do in Gmail with filters and canned responses, except for the one hour delay bit. Your message also appears to have been cut off.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since i have used Mail.app -- I think it was in Tiger -- but I used to have some AppleScripts that I had written to do custom things based on certain criteria. I'd guess that similar functionality is still there. And AppleScript is pretty easy to pick up.

Comment: Hmm, why have you quit using Mail.app? Is there a better alternative? And is there a place where I can get a certain similar applescript (for the illiterate)? If not, where to start learning?

Comment: We started using Zimbra at work, and I fell in love with the Zimbra Desktop Client, which is why I scrapped Mail.app.

Comment: I started learning Apple Script by using google. My first Apple Script was one that used blue tooth proximity with my iPhone to lock the screen, and pause iTunes.